# parse.com - Sort on the included related object in a query

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I have a `register` class that has a pointer to a `student` class. I'd like to be able to sort on the name of the `Student` - is that possible?

```
var Register = Parse.Object.extend("Register");
var regquery = new Parse.Query(Register);

regquery.equalTo("Group", group);
regquery.equalTo("AttDate", date); 
regquery.include("Student");
regquery.ascending(??????); // Is it possible to sort on the name of the Student?
regquery.find({...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible. You need to rethink your data model, or include the `name` field in your `Register` object. This last option is an easy workaround.